# What are the rules for deduced type by "auto" keyword when applied in Objective-C++ to __weak pointer?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11, objective-c++, auto

Let's say I have an Objective-C class Foo:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject
@end
@implementation Foo
@end
```

Then in an objective-C++ file (.mm) I have following code:

```
Foo *strongFoo = [Foo new];
__weak Foo* weakFoo = strongFoo;

auto foo = weakFoo; // ???
```

What is the type of the variable foo on the line containing "???" ? Is it a strong or a weak pointer to Foo? Is this defined somewhere in some standard and/or documentation? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I based on a rule to make a summary:
 1. Objective-C++ does not change rules of C++ and back.

`auto` works differ then `typeof` declaration. `auto` [works](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) similarly templates.

> Once the type of the initialiser has been determined, the compiler
>   determines the type that will replace the keyword `auto` using the rules
>   for [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) from a function call

In the clang docs you can find description of [Ownership Qualification](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id20) in [Template arguments](http://Template%20arguments) part, you can read:

> If a template argument for a template type parameter is an retainable
>   object owner type that does not have an explicit ownership qualifier,
>   it is adjusted to have __strong qualification. This adjustment occurs
>   regardless of whether the template argument was deduced or explicitly
>   specified.

There is good example in the [description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) of `auto` of a template function to determine type of a variable:

> For example, given `const auto& i = expr;`, the type of `i` is exactly the
>   type of the argument `u` in an imaginary template `template<class U> void
>   f(const U& u)` if the function call `f(expr)` was compiled.

As you can see a ownership qualification of const U& is not declared. Therefore `U` is a strong reference to `Foo`.
In your example `auto foo = weakFoo;` will convert to `template<const (Foo*)> f(const Foo*& u)`. As you can see Foo* is a strong reference to a Foo instance.

Comment: Note that you can include an ownership qualifier with `auto`, so `__weak auto` and `__strong auto` are valid and make the ownership explicit – probably a good thing in this situation.